# How to use OpenCV with Repl.it

Tags: python, opencv, import, replit

I would like to write a Python script in Repl.it, but I can't seem to be able to import OpenCV. I am using Repl.it for the first time, so I am not really sure of what I should be doing.

Here are the different things that I tried :

- Just having

```
    import opencv_python as cv2
```

in main.py results in the following console output:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Repl.it: Installing fresh packages
Repl.it:

Collecting opencv_python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/49/874d119948a5a084a7ebe98308214098ef3471d76ab74200f9800efeef15/opencv_python-4.0.0.21-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.11.3 (from opencv_python)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/bf/4981bcbee43934f0adb8f764a1e70ab0ee5a448f6505bd04a87a2fda2a8b/numpy-1.16.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-python
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.1 opencv-python-4.0.0.21
Target directory /home/runner/.site-packages/numpy-1.16.1.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory /home/runner/.site-packages/numpy already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory /home/runner/.site-packages/opencv_python-4.0.0.21.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory /home/runner/.site-packages/cv2 already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Repl.it: package installation success

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import opencv_python as cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opencv_python'
```

It seems the package is installed correctely, but cannot be imported for some reason...?

- I also tried adding a requirements.txt file :

```
    opencv-python==4.0.0.21
```

but this results in a similar output:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Repl.it: Installing fresh packages
Repl.it:

Collecting opencv-python==4.0.0.21 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/49/874d119948a5a084a7ebe98308214098ef3471d76ab74200f9800efeef15/opencv_python-4.0.0.21-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.11.3 (from opencv-python==4.0.0.21->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/bf/4981bcbee43934f0adb8f764a1e70ab0ee5a448f6505bd04a87a2fda2a8b/numpy-1.16.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-python
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.1 opencv-python-4.0.0.21
Target directory /home/runner/.site-packages/numpy-1.16.1.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory /home/runner/.site-packages/numpy already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory /home/runner/.site-packages/opencv_python-4.0.0.21.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory /home/runner/.site-packages/cv2 already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.


Repl.it: package installation success

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import opencv_python as cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opencv_python'
```

- I also tried to import the opencv-python-headless package (both with and without a requirements file), with the same result.
- Finally, I tried using the following line in main.py:

```
import cv2
```

which results in this output:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run_dir/repl.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise EOFError
EOFError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in importing this package!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the repl.it package manager. Do this by pressing the cube icon in the left.
[image: where you can find the cube]

Then, enter the desired package.
[image: where to enter desired package]

Finally, press the plus button.

To import opencv-python, use

```py
import cv2  # When installed opencv-python is already "cv2"
```

Comment: # When installed opencv-python is already "cv2" - that explains so much!

Answer (score 0):

## Import the OpenCV library

import cv2

## Read the image from the file

image = cv2.imread("patrick_bateman.jpg")

## Convert the image to grayscale

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## Load the face detection cascade

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

## Detect the face in the image

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

## Loop over the detected faces

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
# Crop the face region from the image
face = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

```
# Convert the face region to HSV color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Change the hue and saturation values of the hair region to make it black
hsv[0:50, :, 0] = 0 # Hue
hsv[0:50, :, 1] = 255 # Saturation

# Convert the face region back to BGR color space
face = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# Apply a Gaussian blur to the hair region to make it look wet
face[0:50, :] = cv2.GaussianBlur(face[0:50, :], (5, 5), 0)

# Shift some hair pixels down to cover the eye
face[40:50, :] = face[30:40, :]

# Replace the face region in the original image with the modified one
image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = face
```

## Show the modified image

cv2.imshow("Modified Image", image)

## Wait for a key press to exit

cv2.waitKey(0)

## Close all windows

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34936073)

Answer (score -1):

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pytesseract
import imutils

def readImage(filename):
    '''
    Reads an image given its filename 
    using opencv function
    Returns the image as a numpy array
    '''
    img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return img


def converttoGrayscale(img):
    '''
    Converts image from BGR to Grayscale
    Returns the gray image as a numpy array
    '''
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return gray


def thresholdImage(img, threshold_value):
    '''
    Converts a given image into a binary image
    using the thresholding technique
    Returns the binary image as a numpy array
    '''
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, threshold_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    return thresh


def getContours(thresh):
    '''
    Finds all the contours of an image
    Returns a numpy array of x and y coordinates of the contours
    '''
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:10]
    return contours


def getBoundingRect(contour):
    '''
    Returns the x, y width and height of the rectangle defined by 
    the given contour
    '''
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    return x, y, w, h


def cropImage(image, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    '''
    Returns the cropped image based on the given x and y coordinates
    '''
    return image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```